# Without writing any code, is there a command to retrieve the number of available cores in the affinity for the current shell?

Tags: linux, bash, linux-kernel

Assuming Linux, and assuming the current shell was started possibly restricted with taskset, I can write some code to get the current process affinity as

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int getNumberOfAvailableCores() {
    pthread_t self = pthread_self();
    cpu_set_t cpuset;
    CPU_ZERO(&cpuset);
    int res = ::pthread_getaffinity_np(self, sizeof(cpuset), &cpuset);
    int num_cores = 0;
    if ( res!=0 ) return -1;
    for (int j = 0; j < CPU_SETSIZE; j++) {
        if (CPU_ISSET(j, &cpuset)) ++num_cores;
    }
    return num_cores;
}


int main() {
    int num_cores = getNumberOfAvailableCores();
    printf( "%d\n", num_cores );
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/TxT67WWT6

But on machines where I do not even a compiler installed, is there any way to guess the number of available cores?

`getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN` will return the number of processors online, but will not take in consideration the number of cores isolated. Same for grepping `/proc/cpuinfo` or `lscpu`.

I looked into `/proc/self` but would not find a clean way to do it.

Comment: Doesn't `taskset -p $$` work? _"The `taskset` command is used to set or retrieve the CPU affinity of a running process given its pid"_ and `-p` says _"Operate on an existing PID and do not launch a new task."_

Comment: Its promising! But how do I go from the mask to core count on **bash**??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the command `nproc`:

`nproc` -  print the number of processing units available

Example where the affinity mask contains 3 processors:

```bash
$ taskset --cpu-list 0,2,4 bash
$ nproc
3
```

---

My old answer may be useful in case `nproc` isn't available for some reason:

> The `taskset` command is used to set or retrieve the CPU affinity of a running process given its pid

And the `-p` option for `taskset` says:

- Operate on an existing PID and do not launch a new task.

So, you get a hex number with the affinity mask for your process. Example:

```
$ taskset -p $$
pid 1643922's current affinity mask: fff
```

Now, you want to do a [popcount](/questions/tagged/popcount) (count the number of `1`s in the binary representation of the number).

The idea is then to convert the number into its binary form and then count the number of `1`s. Here's a one-liner:

```bash
taskset -p $$ | \
tr '[[:lower:]]' '[[:upper:]]' | \
sed -E 's/.*:\s*/ibase=16;obase=2;/' | bc | tr -d '0\n' | wc -c
```

- `tr '[[:lower:]]' '[[:upper:]]'` - converts the output from `taskset` into uppercase (because `bc` needs uppercase hexadecimal numbers).
- `sed -E 's/.*:\s*/ibase=16;obase=2;/'` - remove the textual output from `taskset` and replace it with instructions for `bc`. `ibase` is the base of the input number (16 = hex) and `obase` is the base we want for the output (2 = binary).

  - At this point we'll have `ibase=16;obase=2;FFF`
- `bc` - Reads `ibase=16;obase=2;FFF` and prints `FFF` as `111111111111`
- `tr -d '0\n'` - Deletes all zeroes and the newline from the output from `bc`
- `wc -c` - count all characters.

In my case, where the affinity mask is `fff`, the output is `12`.

---

Testing: I here start a subshell with 3 processors available and then use the oneliner above from within that shell to figure this out:

```bash
$ taskset --cpu-list 0,2,4 bash
$ taskset -p $$ | \
> tr '[[:lower:]]' '[[:upper:]]' | \
> sed -E 's/.*:\s*/ibase=16;obase=2;/' | bc | tr -d '0\n' | wc -c
3
```

Comment: Good catch! `nproc` seems to be available as far as the ancient Centos-7.

Comment: @HenriqueBucher Great! I can't believe I didn't say that directly. I even use it in my own build scripts - but for some reason, I just didn't remember it for ~20 minutes :)

Comment: I recently isolated 1/2 my cores and the builds started to flood the remaining cores causing all sorts of problems. This fixed it!